GDB linux kernel module - .init.text section overlap .text section?
I'm trying to debug my dynamic module relying on this tutorial: http://oliveryang.net/2016/04/using-kgdb-debug-linux-kernel-3/
I created GDB script that:

connect to target
load vmlinux image
set breakpoint at do_init_module
inspecting struct module to get addresses of the module sections
load symbol file (mymodule.ko)

Between p 3 and 4 I'm loading my module using modprobe
After script finished I'm setting breakpoint on the probe() function (my module is platform device driver)
b motor_device_probe

The problem is that address of init module function is same as my probe function.
I'm building module and linux kernel using YOCTO and meta-raspberrypi (testing on Pi4 hardware
Here are the logs from GDB session:
Setting breakpoints...
Breakpoint 1 at 0xc02e1a98: file /usr/src/kernel/kernel/module.c, line 3675.
[New Thread 276]
[New Thread 259]
[Switching to Thread 276]

Thread 108 hit Breakpoint 1, do_init_module (mod=mod@entry=0xbf245500) at /usr/src/kernel/kernel/module.c:3675
Module name:
$1 = "motor_subsystem", '\000' <repeats 44 times>
Module sections:
number of sections: 20
sections array address: 0xd85fa818
$2 = {{
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18340 ".note.gnu.build-id",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206819840
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18900 ".note.Linux",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206819876
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d188c0 ".text",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206815744
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18a80 ".text.unlikely",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206817172
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18740 ".init.text",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3205361664
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18700 ".exit.text",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206818340
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18bc0 "__jump_table",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206823936
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18c00 ".data",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206828032
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18380 "__bug_table",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206828944
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d180c0 "__dyndbg",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206828960
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18940 ".gnu.linkonce.this_module",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206829312
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18780 ".plt",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206818496
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d183c0 ".rodata",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206819924
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18b80 ".rodata.str1.4",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206820232
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18000 ".rodata.str",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206822206
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18040 "__mcount_loc",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206822296
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18540 ".init.plt",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3205361984
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18ac0 ".bss",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3206829888
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18980 ".symtab",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3205365760
  }, {
    battr = {
      attr = {
        name = 0xd7d18a40 ".strtab",
        mode = 256
      },
      size = 11,
      private = 0x0,
      f_mapping = 0x0,
      read = 0xc02df744 <module_sect_read>,
      write = 0x0,
      mmap = 0x0
    },
    address = 3205369840
  }}
Sections:
section: .note.gnu.build-id | address: 0xbf243000 | 3206819840
section: .note.Linux | address: 0xbf243024 | 3206819876
setting .text section to address: 0xbf242000 | 3206815744
section: .text | address: 0xbf242000 | 3206815744
section: .text.unlikely | address: 0xbf242594 | 3206817172
setting .init.text section to address: 0xbf0df000 | 3205361664
section: .init.text | address: 0xbf0df000 | 3205361664
section: .exit.text | address: 0xbf242a24 | 3206818340
section: __jump_table | address: 0xbf244000 | 3206823936
setting .data section to address: 0xbf245000 | 3206828032
section: .data | address: 0xbf245000 | 3206828032
section: __bug_table | address: 0xbf245390 | 3206828944
section: __dyndbg | address: 0xbf2453a0 | 3206828960
section: .gnu.linkonce.this_module | address: 0xbf245500 | 3206829312
section: .plt | address: 0xbf242ac0 | 3206818496
setting .rodata section to address: 0xbf243054 | 3206819924
section: .rodata | address: 0xbf243054 | 3206819924
setting .rodata.str1.4 section to address: 0xbf243188 | 3206820232
section: .rodata.str1.4 | address: 0xbf243188 | 3206820232
section: .rodata.str | address: 0xbf24393e | 3206822206
section: __mcount_loc | address: 0xbf243998 | 3206822296
section: .init.plt | address: 0xbf0df140 | 3205361984
setting .bss section to address: 0xbf245740 | 3206829888
section: .bss | address: 0xbf245740 | 3206829888
section: .symtab | address: 0xbf0e0000 | 3205365760
section: .strtab | address: 0xbf0e0ff0 | 3205369840
.text: 0xbf242000
.init.text: 0xbf0df000
.bss: 0xbf245740
.rodata: 0xbf243054
.rodata.str1.4: 0xbf243188
.data: 0xbf245000
add symbol table from file "/home/oem/Desktop/motor-subsystem.ko" at
    .text_addr = 0xbf242000
    .data_addr = 0xbf245000
    .bss_addr = 0xbf245740
    .rodata.str1.4_addr = 0xbf243188
    .rodata_addr = 0xbf243054
    .init.text_addr = 0xbf0df000
Symbol "motor_device_probe" is a function at address 0xbf242000.
Symbol "motor_driver_init" is a function at address 0xbf242000.
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0xc02e1a98 in do_init_module at /usr/src/kernel/kernel/module.c:3675
    breakpoint already hit 1 time
        py if str(gdb.parse_and_eval("mod->name")).find("motor_subsystem") != 1: gdb.execute("continue", False, False)
Function "0xbf242000" not defined.
Breakpoint 2 at 0xbf242000: file /usr/src/debug/kernel-module-motor-subsystem/1.0-r0/motor-subsystem/./src/motor-core.c, line 301.
Continuing.

Please look at add-symbol-file call: we see that .init.text address and .text address is different. But when I want to know address of motor_device_probe and motor_driver_init it appears to be the same (?). motor_driver_init is declared with __init macro so it should be placed on .init.text section.

Removing build/tmp dir and rebuilding everything from scratch fixed the issue
